# Grid Pageable Change Font

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a **Kendo** grid that contains the following code. How could I change the font and the font size of the message?

```
pageable: {
  buttonCount: 10,
  messages: {
    display: "{0}-{1} of {2} Stations",
    empty: "",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the message as:

```
display: "<span class='ob-my-style'>{0}-{1} of {2} Stations</span>",
```

where `ob-toto` contains the style definition:

```
.ob-my-style {
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Alternative, you can just define:

```
.k-pager-info.k-label {
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: do you know how to change the font size of the page buttons..the circles with the numbers in them?

Comment: ok nevermind. your alternative was helpful.  i did .k-pager-numbers {
 font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Verdana", sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}